# How to enforce HTTP (instead of HTTPS) while calling gRPC service from Server-Side Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, grpc, blazor-server-side

**Okay, so long story short** :

- I have Blazor Server-Side app.
- I have gRPC service
- Both are running on localhost

**Issue** :

- I can't make it connect via HTTP (though HTTPS works, with self-signed cert)

**What I have tried** :

- Adding
  `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);` to Blazor app `Program.cs` (at very start, before calling builder) and using `services.AddGrpcClient<>();` to add my service client to DI
- Creating client library (wrapper) for my gRPC service and adding same in constructor, just before creating client :

```
        public Client(string url)
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
            _channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(url);
            _client = new SvcTrlClient(_channel);
        }
```

And registering it to Blazor app's DI myself.

**What I get when calling from Blazor** :

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The response ended prematurely.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
```

**Worth mentioning** :

- `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);` works from console app

**Is this enough to disable HTTPS on gRPC side?**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

        .UseSerilog()
        .UseWindowsService()

        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5666, x => x.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
            });

            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Disable Https redirection in Startup Configure

Comment: On which end? Blazor or gRPC? gRPC is listening ONLY on HTTP (port 5000)

Comment: It should be on gRPC side

Comment: I have updated post. Plus I have https url removed from launch options json. When service starts - it is not listening on HTTPS.